# Error no OpenGL support in video driver

Tags: nvidia, graphics, vmware, opengl

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit on VMware on Win 7.

The problem is that after installing [Urho3D](https://urho3d.github.io/) (a game engine) on Ubuntu, it gives the following error when trying to run it:

**ERROR: Could not create window, root cause: 'No OpenGL support in video driver'**

This probably means that I have to install or update the OpenGL or Nvidia Graphics card driver.

These are some info:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/omid/Urho3D/bin# ldd 01_HelloWorld

linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb77de000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xb77c0000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xb77b7000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0xb7724000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb763c000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xb75f6000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb75d9000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb75bd000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb740d000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb77e1000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0xb73e4000)
libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0xb73cb000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xb73b8000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0xb73b4000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0xb73ad000)
libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0xb73aa000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xb7276000)
libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0xb725e000)
libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0xb7258000)
libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0xb7253000)
libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0 (0xb724f000)
libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0xb7248000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xb7226000)
libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1 (0xb7223000)
libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0xb721c000)
libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0xb720c000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xb7208000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xb7201000)
```

and

```
root@ubuntu:/home/omid/Urho3D/bin# lspci -vnn | grep VGA

00:0f.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: VMware SVGA II Adapter 15ad:0405
Subsystem: VMware SVGA II Adapter [15ad:0405]
```

and

```
root@ubuntu:/home/omid/Urho3D/bin# glxinfo | grep OpenGL

OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on SVGA3D; build: RELEASE; 
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 10.3.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
```

So, the question is:

***What should I do !?***

Your time and help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.